# Splunk escaped string regex to extract fields

Tags: splunk

I have a payload as below that has escaped strings, and I need to extract three attributes from this string - requestId, paymentBankType and amountTotal. I have the below query but amountTotal is always coming up as null.

```
index=test "mySearch" | eval _raw=replace(_raw,"\\\\\"","\"") 
|rex "requestId\"\:\"(?<requestID>([^\"]+))"
|rex "paymentBankType\"\:\"(?<paymentBankType>([^\"]+))"
|rex ""amountTotal\"\:\{"currencyAmount\"\:(?<amountTotal>([^\"]+))"
| table requestID, paymentBankType, amountTotal
```

This is my payload. This can vary so I really don't want to feed the query into my Splunk search. I need to filter through millions of such JSON strings, and each can have different values for requestId, paymentBankType and amountTotal. I am really not good at writing Splunk queries.

```
{\"eventId\":\"430215f5-d6e5-4c3d-b1e0-7f36dc22f76d\",\"eventType\":\"TEST\",\"eventTime\":\"2023-03-21T15:04:14.479+0000\",\"eventPayload\":{\"requestId\":\"100000023679171\"\"paymentMethod\":[{\"paymentMethodId\":\"e17579d2-51d6-4b03-a910-49886dcfa21a\",\"paymentBankType\":\"AMEX\",\"paymentType\":\"CREDITCARD\",\"amountTotal\":{\"currencyAmount\":312.11,\"currencyUnit\":\"USD\"}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an unescaped quotation mark in the regex for amountTotal.  Try `| rex "amountTotal\":\{\"currencyAmount\":(?<amountTotal>([^\"]+))"`

Comment: This worked GREAT, thanks @Rich G. But there is a comma now in the end. Any tips on removing it? I can accept the answer after that :)

Comment: I tried "amountTotal\":\{\"currencyAmount\":(?< amountTotal >([^\,"]+))" in regex101, it worked there but splunk is not allowing it.

Comment: Okay this worked - amountTotal\":\{\"currencyAmount\":(?< amountTotal >([^,]+)), thanks so much.